Print QR Codes as labels via ASP.NET MVC application
I have an ASP.NET MVC application where I am generating around 20 QR codes on a button click. I want to print these QR codes using label printer (20 QR codes into 20 labels so that they can be pasted).
The QR code format is:
Image (on 1st line)
Text  (on 2nd line)

Currently I am using the below code to open a dialog with qr codes and it prints on a A4 paper but not as labels.
$("#test2").html(""); 
var divID = 0;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/PrintQRCode/print',
    data: null,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (d) {
        if (d != "") {
            var tr = "<tr>";
            $("#test2").append("<tbody><tr></tr></tbody>");
            $(d.data).each(function (index, row) {
                    tr += "<td><div id=" + divID + "></div><div style='font-size:14px;'><label>" + row.AssetNumber + "</label></div></td>";
                    GenerateQRCode(divID);
                }
                divID = divID + 1;
            });
            tr += "</tr>";
            $("#test2 tbody").append(tr);

            var divContents = document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML;
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=600,width=1000');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Asset Barcodes</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Some errors have occurred. Please try again later");
    }
});
});

On searching, I have found ways to print barcodes using ZPL via Winforms but not via web applications also not specific to QR codes.
Am I missing something or it is the same code of barcodes used for QR codes?

it prints on a A4 paper but not as labels. What are you expecting exactly? The browser does not know which printers are connected...

I agree browsers are not aware about printers. The scenario is I want to download the PDF compatible to be printed locally with label printers.
